# CheckBoxList not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, modalpopupextender, checkboxlist

I have this code. It always gives `fales` for `item.Selected`

```
<asp:Literal ID="LiteralEmployeeList" runat="server" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonRecipients" runat="server">Add/Remove Recipients</asp:LinkButton>
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtenderTo" runat="server" TargetControlID="LinkButtonRecipients"
                    DropShadow="true" PopupControlID="PanelEmployeeList" OkControlID="ButtonOk" EnableViewState="true">
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel ID="PanelEmployeeList" runat="server" Width="200" Height="100" ScrollBars="Vertical">
    <div id="DivPanelBody">
        <div id="DivList">
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxListEmployee" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"
                onselectedindexchanged="CheckBoxListEmployee_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:CheckBoxList>                
        </div>
        <div id="DivControls">
            <asp:Button ID="ButtonOk" runat="server" Text="Ok" />
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

`CheckBoxList` is bound to a data source and its working.

```
protected void CheckBoxListEmployee_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LiteralEmployeeList.Text = string.Empty;

    foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxListEmployee.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            LiteralEmployeeList.Text += item.Text + ", ";
        }
    }
}
```

any idea whats wrong? thanx..

Comment: Is it not item.Checked?

Comment: no. there is no `item.Checked`

Comment: Show me you page_Load function. Did you check isPostback before init your checkboxlist?

Comment: @DoanCuong yes It is the problem. now its working thanx

Comment: You're welcome!! Have fun with coding :D

Answer (score 2):

try this...

```
for (int i = 0; i < interestedIN.Items.Count; i++)
{
   if (interestedIN.Items[i].Selected)
   {
       values += interestedIN.Items[i].Value + ",";
   }
}

values = values.TrimEnd(',');
```

Comment: you mean for a button click event on panel? I tried it once, but did no good. same result :(

Comment: try to replace your code with this within same EVENT...and see if it works.

Comment: as @DoanCuong says problem in the page load. I forgot to check `IsPostBack`. anyway thanx..